# HAProxy / Head requests with unicode characters in URI

Tags: unicode, http-headers, haproxy, cyrillic, unicode-escapes

I just figured out HAProxy has an issue (returns 400 Bad Request) when using unencoded unicode characters in the URI - like this:

[http://www.something.com/адрес](http://www.something.com/%D0%B0%D0%B4%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%81)

I am intentionally not encoding the path part of the URI as it's a cyr HTML5+ website and if i have to escape everything things become really messy.

So far i haven't had any issues with ordinary web servers and browsers but as soon.

But - today when testing with a SEO web tool which apparently uses HEAD requests to check the validity of links it told me pretty much most links were bad/broken.

Then i tested a HEAD request as noted and it really fails - every time.

The only way to 'fix' this is if i use the 'accept-invalid-http-request' option but that is not a production thing to use...

Any other suggestions?

Is it a MUST that i have to encode all URI unicode characters (keeping in mind i do not care for compat with old OS-es like XP or so)?

Comment: You tested with a `HEAD` request... how?  One possibility is that the "SEO web tool" was written by someone who doesn't know how to make proper HTTP requests. The user-agent has a responsibility for encoding unencoded URL components correctly.

Comment: What i did was: curl -I http://www.something.com/адрес - which gives: HTTP/1.0 400 Bad request
Cache-Control: no-cache
Connection: close
Content-Type: text/html

The page i am testing is: http://www.piraprint.com/отдели

This is a HEAD request - which obviously fails. It is behind HAProxy.

The same call works perfectly fine if directly behind NGINX.